# find all anagrams of a given word

Tags: java

I wrote this program which generates anagrams for a given word.
The init function will create a dictionary of words. it can be read from a text file or array. Here I'm reading words from an array to create my dictionary.
I would like some advice on how to optimize this code or any changes or suggestions needed to improve efficiency of this code is appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Solution {

    static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    private void addToMap(String key, String word) {
        ArrayList<String> anagramList = dictionaryMap.get(key);

        if (anagramList == null) {
            anagramList = new ArrayList<String>();
            anagramList.add(word);
            dictionaryMap.put(key, anagramList);

        }
        if (!anagramList.contains(word)) {
            anagramList.add(word);
            dictionaryMap.put(key, anagramList);
        }
    }

    private String createMap(String word) {
        Map<Character, Integer> characterCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        char arr[] = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String sortString = Arrays.toString(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < sortString.length(); i++) {
            char c = sortString.charAt(i);
            if (characterCountMap.containsKey(c))
                characterCountMap.put(c, characterCountMap.get(c) + 1);
            else
                characterCountMap.put(c, 1);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : characterCountMap.entrySet())
            buff.append(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());

        return buff.toString();
    }

    private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> init(String[] words) {
        for (String word : words) {
            addToMap(createMap(word), word);

        }
        return dictionaryMap;
    }

    private String[] getAnagrams(String word) {

        String key = createMap(word);
        List<String> al = dictionaryMap.get(key);
        String[] arr = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution obj = new Solution();
        System.out.println("This is a debug message");
        String arr[] = { "ate", "eat", "THIS", "EAT" };
        obj.init(arr);
        for (String anagram : obj.getAnagrams("tea"))
            System.out.println(anagram);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you generating only exact anagrams or can an anagram consist of two or more words?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. It seems me for every word you create a key in your map concatenating ascii code of chars and the number of occurrences after sorting and then anagrams have the same representation, could you give more informations about this algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

This is what I think about it

## General Coding

### program against interfaces

Most of your variables are defines as *concrete types* (classes you actually instantiate). 
You should better declare them as *interface types* so that it is possible to exchange 
the concrete implementation without changing the code all over.

example

```
static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

should better be

```
static Map<String, List<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

or even

```
static Map<String, Collection<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Problem here is that you need to know what interfaces are available and what the 
consequences are using them. The [public API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/overview-tree.html) 
is the place to find that information.

### Be consistent

Choose the same approach for the same problem

E.g. you use two different types of loops

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sortString.length(); i++) {
        char c = sortString.charAt(i);
    //...
    // vs.
    for (String word : words) {
        addToMap(createMap(word), word);
    //...
```

Unless you really need the index variable for something else then accessing the actual 
object in the collection loops over you could (and should) stick to the *foreach* 
form

```
    for (char c : sortString.toCharArray()) {
```

### Learn about the capabilities of the objects provided by the runtime

Especially the class `Map` has some interesting methods your code could benefit from: 
The code

```
    ArrayList<String> anagramList = dictionaryMap.get(key);
    if (anagramList == null) {
        anagramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        anagramList.add(word);
        dictionaryMap.put(key, anagramList);
    }
```

could be replaced by

```
    ArrayList<String> anagramList = dictionaryMap.computeIfAbsent(key,()->new ArrayList<String>());
```

If you would know that beside (`Array-`)`List` which allows duplicates, the *Java 
Runtime* provides another collection type `Set` which does not hold duplicates, then 
you could even get rid of the other `if` in this method too:

```
static Map<String, Collection<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();

private void addToMap(String key, String word) {
    dictionaryMap.computeIfAbsent(key,()-> new HashSet<String>())
                 .add(word);
 }
```

### Avoid arrays

instead of arrays better use `Collection` types like any implementations of the `List` 
and  `Set` interfaces. They are more flexible and prevent you to copy data (yourself) 
when its size needs to be changed.

### use the `static` key word with intention

You declared the variable `dictionaryMap` as a *class variable* although it is not 
accessed by any  static method. Unless you understand the consequences you should not use the `static` key word.

### narrow your interfaces

Your method `init()` has a return value which is not needed since there is no caller 
of this method dealing with this return value. Methods with return value usually 
are harder to refactor. Especially its harder to split them into smaller methods.

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to 
think about the names of your identifiers

### Please read (and follow) the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

This does not only apply to the casing of the identifiers. 
It also applies to how names are "constructed".
E.g.: you named a method `getAnagrams()`. 
By conventions the prefix *get* is reserved for methods, that do not do any processing 
but simply return a property of the object.
But your method does a lot more than that.
Therefore a better name could be `findAnagramsOf(String word)`.

### avoid single character names

Since the number of characters is quite limited in most languages you will soon run 
out of names. This means that you either have to choose another character which is 
not so obviously connected to the purpose of the variable. And/or you have to "reuse" 
variable names in different contexts. Both makes your code hard to read and understand 
for other persons. (Keep in mind that you are that other person yourself if you look 
at your code in a few month!)

On the other hand in Java the length of identifier names is virtually unlimited. 
There is no penalty in any way for long identifier names. So don't be stingy with 
letters when choosing names.

### Choose your names from the problem domain

Some of your identifiers (or at least parts of them) have technical meaning. 
But your identifiers should convey you *business solution*.

example: `characterCountMap`,  `c`, `sortString` or `arr`.

Remember that the technical details may change while the meaning of your identifiers 
in respect to the business problem will remain.
so this identifiers might better be:

`characterCounts`, `currentCharacter`, `sortedCharacters` or `wordCharacters`.

Comment: I believe `getOrDefault` isn't the right method you want to use. `getOrDefault` doesn't write the value back into the map. It should be `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: @RoToRa yes, you're right. Thanks for spotting that. I updated the answer.

Comment: It isn't quite right yet. You still have an `getOrDefault` example and also the second argument of `computeIfAbsent` needs to be a `Supplier<>` (`() -> new ArrayList<String>()` or `ArrayList<String>::new`)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite complicated. It's possible to do it in a much simpler way. But to do that, you have to know a trick about anagrams:

> Iff two words are anagrams of each other, their sorted characters are the same.

This means that you don't need to count each character in a map, you can just take a string, sort its characters (like you already do), make it a string again (which you also do) and use this string as the key to the map.

When you abstract the problem further, it can be seen as a map, in which multiple entries can be stored for each key. This is also something that your code already does. The crucial point is how the key is calculated. You already defined a method for that and called it `createMap`. That name is wrong. That method does not create a map, it computes the *key* instead.

Your key generation method should be as simple as:

```java
private String key(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

One area where you can improve your code a lot is how you name the variables. Right now you named most of the variables based on their type. For example, `al` is a list. It probably was an `ArrayList` somewhere in the past, that's where the `a` might originate from. Or the `a` means `anagram`, in which case the variable should really have been called `anagrams`.

In general, variable names should represent the *purpose* of the variable, not the *data type*. The data type is easy to see if you have a good editor, but the purpose is much more important to express.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from beginning: you defined a class `Solution` containing a `map` like below:

> ```
> public class Solution {
>     static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
> }
> ```

With the use of `ArrayList` the map can contains duplicates of string : to avoid this issue you can use a `Set` and specifically a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) because when you iterate over keys, they are ordered by their natural ordering. So the class can be rewritten like below:

```
public class Solution {
    private Map<String, Set<String>> map;

    public Solution() {
        this.map =new TreeMap<>();
    }
}
```

Once you defined the class in this way you can define two methods `addWords` and `addWord` to add words to your dictionary like below:

```
public void addWords(String[] words) {
    for (String word : words) {
        addWord(word);
    }
}

private void addWord(String word) {
    String key = generateKey(word);

    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(word)));
    } else {
        Set<String> set = map.get(key);
        set.add(word);
    }
}
```

You can check inside the method `addWord` the method `generateKey` is called to generate the key corresponding to the word you are trying to include in your dictionary; if the key is not already contained in your map  a new `TreeSet` containing the word will be created and associated to the key in the map, otherwise the word is an anagram of a word already present in the dictionary and will be added to the existing `TreeSet`.

The most important method of the program is the `generateKey` method that generate a representation of the word you want to insert in your dictionary, I'm using a representation formed by concatenation of chars of word and their occurrences sorted in alphabethic order:

- "tea" -> a1e1t1
- "eat" -> a1e1t1

Below the code of the method generateKey;

```
private static String generateKey(String word) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    char arr[] = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (char key : arr) {
        int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0);
        map.put(key, ++value);
    }

    Set<Character> set = map.keySet();
    for (Character ch : set) {
        builder.append(ch + Integer.toString(map.get(ch)));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

You can check I used inside the method a `TreeMap` to obtain characters keys already naturally ordered, so I don't need to use `sort` method like your code.

The final method is the method `getAnagrams` that returns the list of anagrams of the word in a array that can be empty if the word or its anagrams are present in the dictionary (I would prefer this method returns an unmodifiable collection instead of array):

```
public String[] getAnagrams(String word) {
    String key = generateKey(word);
    Set<String> set = map.getOrDefault(key, new TreeSet<>());
    return set.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Here the complete code of class Solution:

**Solution.java**

```
package codereview;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Solution {
    private Map<String, Set<String>> map;

    public Solution() {
        this.map =new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public void addWords(String[] words) {
        for (String word : words) {
            addWord(word);
        }
    }

    private void addWord(String word) {
        String key = generateKey(word);

        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(word)));
        } else {
            Set<String> set = map.get(key);
            set.add(word);
        }
    }

    private static String generateKey(String word) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char arr[] = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        for (char key : arr) {
            int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0);
            map.put(key, ++value);
        }

        Set<Character> set = map.keySet();
        for (Character ch : set) {
            builder.append(ch + Integer.toString(map.get(ch)));
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public String[] getAnagrams(String word) {
        String key = generateKey(word);
        Set<String> set = map.getOrDefault(key, new TreeSet<>());
        return set.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution obj = new Solution();
        System.out.println("This is a debug message");
        String words[] = { "ate", "eat", "THIS", "EAT" };
        obj.addWords(words);
        for (String anagram : obj.getAnagrams("tea"))
            System.out.println(anagram);
    }
}
```